# Launch Twitter with selected user from wp8 application

Tags: windows-phone-8, launcher

I am trying to launch twitter with selected user from my WP8 application and it does not work so good.

In my click event for the button that will do the job the code looks like this:

```
private void Button_Click_3(object sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("twitter:@user"));
}
```

When I click the button I get a message that asks if I want to search the app in the store but i have Twitter installed so what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the twitter app supports app to app coms? this might be your issue ill look into it later

Comment: Ok. I dont know but it whould be nice if it did ;)

Comment: So the only option is to use i hyperlink for this.